# MediaWiki - How to subscribe users to be notified to ALL edits

Tags: mediawiki

There are 2-3 people that must approve all changes in my MediaWiki.  I'd like when a change is submitted for those people to receive an email.  I keep stumbling across ways of doing this with admins subscribing to pages and such, but I don't want to mess with having to subscribe an admin, I'd like it all to be automatic.

Is there a setting or extension that I've overlooked?

Comment: What extension do you use, FlaggedRevisions?

Comment: @Dereckson I'm not sure I understand your question, I currently don't use any extension that helps with this, but am looking for one that will help.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set [$wgUsersNotifiedOnAllChanges](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUsersNotifiedOnAllChanges) in your `LocalSettings.php` like

```
$wgUsersNotifiedOnAllChanges = array('admin1@example.org', 'admin2@example.org');
```

If you want fancier customisation, there are several extensions like [Recent Activity Notify](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Recent_Activity_Notify), [AutoWatch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AutoWatch) (apparently used on one 1.24 wiki) and [WatchEmailOptional](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WatchEmailOptional) but they are rather old, [patches welcome](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Tutorial) if they don't work!